# Get attribute text field on front-end product page?

Tags: product-attribute, custom-attributes

I'm looking to retrieve the value of an attribut with the ID "size_clamp" and show it on the short and long description of my product. I have tried to add the following code directly in the short description area on the back-end but no luck :

- "This clamp has an exterior size `<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText("size_clamp"); ?>` for clamping on the tube"...

This gives me an error on the front end. I was hopping for the following result :

- "This clamp has an exterior size **27mm** for clamping on the tube"

Here is why i'm looking for this :

- Avoid repetitive manual input in the text for thousand products, it's the same clamps with different sizes. I want to have a default text with those shortcode and just paste it in both short and long description.
- Seo reason, i was thinking to create an attribut called "seo_text" that is different per store view which would change based on the store view. This could avoid having duplicate content on google.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

If you want product attribute value on front-end, Please try below method-:

**Method1** :-

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $product->getResource()->getAttribute('size_clamp')->getFrontend()->getValue($product); ?>
```

**Method2**:-

```
<div><?php echo $_product->getData('size_clamp'); ?></div>
```

**Method3**:-

```
<div><?php echo $product->getCustomAttribute('size_clamp'); ?></div>
```

Verify attribute Yes for frontend:-

**Admin -> Stores -> Attributes -> Product ->**

Find your attribute in list and click on edit
Click on  `Storefront Properties` tab and check  `Allow HTML Tags on Storefront` and `Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront` are `YES`

Comment: Hi MP Raj, thank you for your fast return. I've copied both codes in the short description area on the product page but no luck, i get the following on the front-end "getData('code_produit'); ?>". I've change the attribut to "code_product" which is a simple texte field attribut in case that was the problem.

Comment: Can you please tell me what type of attribute in Admin and Magento verstion ?

Comment: Please check updated answer

Comment: By not being able to add php directly in the short description tab, i will not be able to add the value inside a specific place (like inside a phrase). Is there no other way to achieve this ? I've read something about dynamic text being used for seo, that should be the same idear !

Comment: Or a widget that calls the specific attribut ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below methods :

```
$attributeCode = 'attribute_text_field';
$attributeValue = $product->getData($attributeCode);
```

Or

```
$product->getCustomAttribute('attribute_text_field');
```

or

```
$product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_text_field')->getFrontend()->getValue($product)
```

Comment: Hi Divyarajsinh Barad, thank you for your response. Unfortunatly as i understand i cannot add this code directly on the short description tab in magento ? Do you know a way it ?

Comment: Please use  "<?= $block->getProduct()->getShortDescription(); ?>" this and let me know if any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. I'm running on magento 2.4.5 and i've added a screenshot of my attribut to make it easier.

[image: attribut]

And this is where i'm trying to input the value :

[image: description]

Regards,
Marc

Comment: PHP code will not work in backend description and short description tab. You can add hard value there.

Comment: That is what i'm looking for ;) Maybe i need to change my question at the beginning to be more precise, "hard value" is that the right term ?